# How to get the highest data from different columns in sql

Tags: sql

I have 3 different forms loaded with data(rows) but they have different versions.

Every time I update one of the forms the version goes up. My syntax is something like this:

```
    f.NR_FORM AS NR_FORM,
    f.NR_VERSION AS NR_VERSION
from 
    ficha f
where 
    f.COD_EMPRESA = 1
    and f.NR_FICHARIO = '14'
group by 
    f.NR_FICHA;
```

By using this I can only get the first version of the forms. I want to get the latest version of each one.

Comment: Edit your question and show the complete query.  Also, sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: Not sure If I'm missing something here but have you tried doing an order by NR_Version desc?

Comment: maybe stupid. But why don't you add a max() in your select or an order By at the end?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I want the latest version of each row, even if they are different

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html): (It's the manual from MySQL, but the examples should work with every RDBMS. Only standard SQL is used)

### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column

> *Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most
>   expensive price.*
>
> This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
    FROM   shop s1
    WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
                  FROM shop s2
                  WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

> The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be
>   inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other
>   possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated
>   subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN. Uncorrelated subquery:

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

> LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

> The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum
>   value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows
>   values will be NULL.